# Set and List distinction - Golan Linear Algebra book

Tags: linear-algebra

He says:

> A ﬁnite or countably-inﬁnite selection of elements of a set $A$ is a list.

then he says:

> Note that the elements of a list need not be distinct:

Taking the case of a list with non-distinct elements, how does one go about building a list from a set? A set has only distinct (unique) elements so this would rule out a direct copy/subset creation.. which means the elements are picked and then repeated in the list?

Comment: I don't know what a "selection" is. In any case, a *list* $\ell$ of length $N$ with elements from the set $A$ is a map $$\ell:\ [N]\to A, \quad k\mapsto\ell_k\ ,$$ and is denoted by $(\ell_k)_{1\leq k\leq N}$, or similar. The *entries* $\ell_k$ of the list need not be distinct.

Comment: I would take a selection to be a function $f:\{1,...,n\} \to A$ or $f:\mathbb{N} \to A$.

Comment: @c.blatter: so what you are saying is that $\ell$ is a map from the set $\{1, ..., N\}$ to A, such that element $\ell_k$ which belongs to set A, is assigned to k in the set of length N. BUT, this is incomplete because all you are doing is providing an index(k) to the list(A) - which is a programming definition. If you look at the mathematical definition, if the list is a finite set/selection then its mapped through an injective function and if its a countably-infinite set/selection then its mapped through a bijection. What I'm unclear about is the repeatability of list elements in math form.